# Gdalwarp - Clip Raster by Mask - Missing Pixels (Cutline)

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I am clipping two - partly overlapping - geotiffs with Gdalwarp by the same shapefile, wich I want to merge in a next step. This works well, but after merging the rasters, I noticed that some pixels are missing along side the cutline/ clipline of the inputshapefile.

Is there any option, which allows to include the pixels of the cutline?

Comment: I am not certain about what the `-cblend` option does https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html but it may be worth a try. Also the target aligned pixels `-tap` could help. If the latter removes the empty pixels I would prefer to use it.

Comment: Hi. thanks, i played around with -cblend, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: How about -tap?